# Django - Python help_text as a clickable icon

Tags: django, python-2.7, icons, clickable

I want to add help text to my forms.  However, I want it to appear as a small question mark icon to the right of the input box, when clicked on, will show the `help_text`.

I have a way of doing it through the html, but when I have more than one field with `help_text`, its gets buggy.

Main question, anyway of doing this using Django and not the html?  If so, what would the steps be to implement?

Thanks

Comment: are you talking on a front end form or in the admin?

Comment: I am talking about on the front end, so the users can click on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `templatetag`, something along these lines should work (untested)

```
@register.simple_tag
def render_help_text(field):
    if hasattr(field, 'help_text'):
        return mark_safe(
            "<a><img src='/static/img/icons/help.gif' title='{help_text}' /></a>".format(**{'help_text': field.help_text})
        )
    return ''
```

*template*

```
{% for field in form %}
    <!-- other stuff -->
    {% render_help_text field %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That was a round about way, but still worked.  I ended up just putting title='{{ help_text }}' in the image tag.  You gave me the idea though, or well pointed it out! :D thanks!